# Java Implementing Interface Declared in Abstract Class

Tags: java, class, interface

Consider my following example structure:

```
public interface MyInterface 
{
    public void doSomething();
}

public interface MyInterface2 
{
    public void doSomethingElse();
}

public class MyAbstract implements MyInterface, MyInterface2
{
    @Override
    public void doSomething()
    {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomethingElse()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

So I have 2 Interfaces that an AbstractClass implements.

If I have an implementation of the AbstractClass `MyImpl`, which extends `MyAbstract`, it seems like I don't have to declare `implements MyInterface` and `MyInterface2`

But is it better practice to do so?

```
public class MyImpl extends MyAbstract
    implements MyInterface, MyInterface2
{

}
```

vs

```
public class MyImpl extends MyAbstract
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should choose the second version

```
public class MyImpl extends MyAbstract
{

}
```

The fact that you're extending the class that implements the interfaces is enough to infer that your concrete class also implements those interfaces as the contract is transitive.  Adding the interfaces to your implementation is just duplication.

Comment: I was just wondering if the duplicate declaration of implementing the interface in the implementatoin has any benefit in terms of maintainability and readability.

Comment: YMMV but I would say in terms of readability, but could cost you for maintenance, e.g. the class you inherit from changes the interfaces it implements, you now have to change that in multiple places

Answer (score 0):

Extending any class allows us to override the methods of super class when it is required , but when we implement an interface we have to define all the methods of the interface mandatorly.

Answer (score 0):

Your second version is enough, because when your class inherit from a first class you can reuse all the properties (fields, methods, inheritance and Implementing Interfaces...) of the first class.

You can find more here:[Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)